# Call to undefined function dba_handlers()

Tags: php, berkeley-db

I looked in my php.ini for an option to enable the DBA extension and I found "php_dba.dll". However in the "ext" folder there is no such file with this name. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file which contains

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and open it on your Webserver. Check there if the Berkeley db is mentioned anywhere.

If you found nothing follow http://www.php.net/manual/en/dba.installation.php also take care of the warning notice on this page.

dba_handlers() is available in PHP since the version 4.3 do you have at least 4.3? Is there a error message about missing php_dba.dll when you restart your server?

Comment: all these points don't really help if there is not `php_dba.dll` - which (_where can i get it_) is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.5. I have downloaded the 5.3.6 build from php.net site but there is nothing to do with. I googled for this file and downloaded it but after restarting Apache, PHP still give errors :(

Comment: It's still "Call to undefined function dba_handlers()".

Seems that I have downloaded wrong file and I need to learn to build my own PHP with this extension.